# How can I give custom IP address in my HoloLens?

Tags: hololens

I have one HoloLens and I want to add my WIFI Network to that. But for some Security reasons, we need to provide custom unique IP address to our HoloLens. I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help me out?

I have tried **"Windows Device Portal"** but can't see any option to change current IP address in that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in the HoloLens, but I do know that you can do this on the router, yes?

Comment: Till now I found no way to assign custom IP address in HoloLens but assigning IP from Router is the only solution. But in my company different floors have different routers, so that method is not the BEST one. If any one found any other answer then please contribute. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Get the MAC address of hololens, go to your router, and assign it a static IP address. Should be under your DHCP settings.

Answer (score 2):

This is a couple years late, but this is possible (now).

After connecting your hololens to your PC via USB, open the debug interface, usually at http://127.0.0.1:10080.  Navigate to System > Networking and under the IP Configuration heading you can find the wifi adapter and click "IPv4 Configuration" and set your custom settings there.

[image]